# Is it possible to open a link on Safari for iOS by tapping the link on Chrome for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, cross-browser

I am going to capture the images from camera on web app.
It works well on most browsers for Android, but only Safari for iOS.

So If user uses the chrome as default broswer on iOS, Is it possible to open a link on Safari for iOS by tapping the link on Chrome for iOS automatically?

If so, please share the Javascript code snippet.

Comment: Please don't tag iOS questions with [android].

Comment: I think you are looking for protocol handler, but cross browser I don't think so.